# Remove submenu items

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to remove submenu items. I want to keep the first 2 items and remove all the rest.
The text of the first two is "Beheer" and a seperator "-".

I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count; i++)
{
    if (this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[i].Text != "&Beheer")
    {
        if ( this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[i].Text != "-")
        {
            this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This does not remove all the items.

Comment: When removing from a list it is always better to start from the bottom and work your way up. Because removing an item from the list might change the index that you are using in your loop. Working from bottom up does not have that problem

Comment: it's called reverse or backward loop : `for (int i = this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count -1; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the first two items, just do this:

```
while ( this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count > 2 )
    this.oracleToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(2);
```

The RemoveAt(2) will remove the 3rd item, assuming one exists.  We do this until only 2 exist.

(2) is the third item because the first one is (0).

Comment: Maybe you could explain why your numeral "2" must be used in `RemoveAt()` - to not make is look like a magic number.

Comment: Yes, partially - but telling people that the former 4th element, for example, will then be the third element and so on would be quite a good additive to your answer.